# Smooth function from regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I Came across this following example from previous year class notes:
let $f:S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R} f(x,y,z)=z$ so $f$ is the restriction of $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x,y,z)=z$ to the sphere $S^2$.
Therefor $F$ is linear transformation and $$DF|_p(v_1 ,v_2, v_3)=F(v_1 ,v_2, v_3)=v_3$$ for every $p\in \mathbb{R}^3$, in other words the differential  $DF|_p$ in the regular basis is $$DF|p=(0,0,1)$$ and therefor exists that $$df|_p(v_1 ,v_2, v_3)=DF|_p(v_1 ,v_2, v_3)=v_3$$
My questions:

1. Why does the last equation holds? $df|_p(v_1 ,v_2, v_3)=DF|_p(v_1 ,v_2, v_3)=v_3$
2. I think that there should be $p$'s s.t. $df|_p=0$ because the poles of the sphere are critical points for $f$ but on the other hand $DF|_p$ isn't the zero vector for every $p$

Comment: What is $df$ in front of $DF$ ?

Comment: I copies the symbols as is. $df$ for my understanding is the differential of $f$.

Comment: so shouldn't it be $dF$, the differential of $F$ :/ ? (Just trying to get the environnement you're evolving in)

Comment: $f$ is the restriction of $F$ to the sphere. Well- what you asked is the question Im asking. Or I didn't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Just a guess, but to my mind it would have made sense to use $d$ instead of $D$ but as far as I am a computer scientist and not a mathematician wait for one to confirm

Comment: You are right, that notation also got my notice, but again- I copied the exact notation so that nothing will be missed.

Comment: You may ask your teacher then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last equation doesn't hold. $df_p$ is a function from the $2$-dimensional space $TS^2_p$ to the $1$-dimensional $T\mathbb{R}_{f(p)}$. For that reason, it is not clear what the notation $df_p(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ means.

There are indeed points where $df_p=0$. Assume that $p=(0,0,1)$ (as you said, the other point is $(0,0,-1)$). Then a tangent vector at $p$ is an [equivalence class of smooth curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_the_velocity_of_curves) $g=(g_1,g_2,g_3):\mathbb{R}\to S^2$ such that $g(0)=p$. This means, in particular, that $g_3\leq1$ and $g_3(0)=1$. Then $df_p([g])=[f\circ g]_p=[g_3]_p$. Since $g_3$ has a maximum at $t=0$, the derivative of $g_3$ at $t=0$ is $0$. Therefore, $[g_3]_p=[1]_p$, which is the zero in the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}$ at $f(p)=1$.

So, $df_{p}$, for $p=(0,0,1)$ sends all tangent vectors at $p$ to the zero tangent vector to $\mathbb{R}$ at $1$.

On the other hand $dF_p$, for $p=(0,0,1)$ is not the zero linear map. Consider the class of $g(t)=(0,0,1+t)$ in $T\mathbb{R}^3_{p}$. Then $dF_p([g])=[F\circ g]=[1+t]$, which is not the same class as $[1]$ because the derivative of $1+t$ is $1$, which is different from the derivative of $1$, which is $0$. Therefore $dF_p$ is not the zero function.

Comment: but isn't $TS^2_p$ is subset of R3? for my understanding, that is the tangent plane to $S^2$, which is the unit ball in R3, at the point $p$

Comment: @YaronScherf You could view it as a subset, yes. For example, you could identify $TS^2_p$, for $p=(0,0,1)$, to be the set $\{(x,y,1):\ x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, with addition only on the first two components. But still $df_p$ would have to send them all to the zero vector in the corresponding tangent space of $\mathbb{R}$.